# Windows RT PNG file access on an external USB hard drive

Tags: c#, image, png, windows, removable-storage

I'm very confused about accessing PNG files on my USB external hard drive.

Even tough I've added the Removable Storage capability and added the `.png` file type to the declaration tab,  every time I try to bind an image from XAML

```
i.e:(Source="{Binding MyImagePathName}")
```

nothing gets binded.

I tried programmatic access to the location and manual binding in C# to an image control and it raised the image load failed.

However I tried the same techniques, but with the app installation folder instead and it miraculously works. What am I doing wrong, am I missing a piece of information?

Note: It does work with `.json` files but not the `.png`.

Help I'm struggling with that for a week now!

Comment: Seems that there is an internal mechanic that prevent a direct binding using a path (sand box environment I presume), even tough you have enabled Removable Storage capability. I resolved by loading the bitmap image in stream (using code) and assigning the bitmapimage to a property in my data object, then bind in XAML using that property instead of the path.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is an internal mechanic that prevent a direct binding using a path (sand box environment I presume), even tough you have enabled Removable Storage capability. I resolved by loading the bitmap image in stream (using code) and assigning the bitmapimage to a property in my data object, then bind in XAML using that property instead of the path.